# Python Word occurrence

Tags: python, counter, cpu-word

I'm trying to open and read a text file and count the number of types a word occurs for example if the word better is in the text it would have a frequency of 8. I have attached the code below. I got the following error

> UnicodeDecodeError:  'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 861: invalid start byte

```
file=open('IntroductoryCS.txt')

wordcount={}

for word in file.read().split():
        if word not in wordcount:
           wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
           wordcount[word] += 1

for k,v in wordcount.items():
      print k, v
```

I am using IDLE 3.5.1

Comment: It seems your file contains non utf-8 encoding. try to decode with proper encoding type then try the same

Comment: non utf-8 encoding ? sorry I am new to programming

Comment: @RK1- please refer this, https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html. first find your suitable encoding style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you IntroductoryCS.txt is not in UTF-8.

You should change encoding in open() function.

Something like this:

```
file=open('IntroductoryCS.txt', encoding='<your_encoding_here>')
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

I don't know what encoding is your file but try this:

```
file=open('IntroductoryCS.txt', encoding='latin-1')
```

Here are avalaible [encodings](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help the code was fine and there was an error within the original text file

Comment: @RK1 I think you should accept the answer if it helps you. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine.

Try to save the txt file as `UTF-8`. Open the file on notepad, then save as, and choose encoding `UTF-8`.

Comment: Managed to get it working there was an error with the text file